# Trying to use Vlookup on a table with filtered data with changing number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have already have created a table that has a table of filtered data. After this, I am wanting to apply the VLookup command with uses the date and lookups the Work Order associated with that date. (This should only returns one work order per date)

This is what I have so far. Some problems that I think I may having is after I change the size of the table as this range changes as each filtered is applied.

```
            Dim DeliverableTablefltrdRng As Range
            Set DeliverableTablefltrdRng = rRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                           
            Dim cel As Range
            Dim DeliverableDate As Date
        
            For Each cel In Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                
                'Now we need to verify if the date from the for loop falls
                'between our inputed start and end date
                DeliverableDate = cel
                If ((DeliverableDate >= Start_Date) And (DeliverableDate <= End_Date)) Then
                    'This "if" statement states that we have found a value between the deliverable dates
                    'Next let's record the work order associated for this project
                    
                    'We can achieve this by using a vlookup command
                    workOrder = Application.VLookup(DeliverableDate, DeliverableTablefltrdRng, 6)
                    'DeliverableTablefltrdRngDeliverableTable = Sheet1.Range
                    Debug.Print cel
                    Debug.Print workOrder
                Else
                End If 
             Next cel
```

Comment: You say you think you may have problems - it helps to describe exactly why you think that.  What is your code doing/not doing which is different from what you want/expect it to do?

Comment: My vlookup isn't working. I tried using Debug.Print, but it keep returning 2042. I need it to return the work order from deliverable date. The work order is in column 6.

Comment: You can't use vlookup against a multi-area range as you often get from `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`: the lookup table needs to be a regular contiguous range.